# Datastax OpsCenter - Can't connect to Cassandra All host(s) tried for query failed

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I have a two node and I installed DataStax OpsCenter on 10.5.0.201 but **I give error ( Unable connect to any seed nodes )** when I create new cluster on OpsCenter. Can you check my config ?

**address.yaml ( 10.5.0.201 )**
[image]

**address.yaml ( 10.5.0.203 )**
[image]

**nodetool status**
[image]

**DataStax OpsCenter**
[image]

**startup.log (10.5.0.201)**
[image]

**agent.log ( 10.5.0.201 )**
[image]

**Versions**

- Python 2.6.6
- java version "1.8.0_74"
- Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_74-b02) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.74-b02, mixed mode)
- OpsCenter 5.2.4

Best Regards

Comment: Can you provide the value of 1) listen_address 2) rpc_addres in the `cassandra.yaml` files of Cassandra machines ?

Comment: @doanduyhai  cassandra.yaml for 10.5.0.201 => 1) listen_address: 10.5.0.201  2) rpc_address: 0.0.0.0

Comment: Can you please check the status of firewall and if it's active, turn off the firewall and then try?

Answer (score 0):

In the comments of `cassandra.yaml`

```
# Note that unlike listen_address, you can specify 0.0.0.0, but you must also
# set broadcast_rpc_address to a value other than 0.0.0.0.
```

I would recommend to set `rpc_address: 10.5.0.201` for the 1st node and to retry

Comment: I did it but still same error ((( I need to resolve this problem. Help me please

Comment: If you are still facing same issue even after setting rpc address, can you please post the updated log?

Comment: @Abhinandan I am sorry where updated log path, Do you want to see agent.log or startup.log ?

Comment: Not an issue.It will be great, if you provide both the logs.Also, can you please check the status of firewall and if it's active, turn off the firewall and then try?

Comment: @Abhinandan I checked and firewall is off ( service iptables status => iptables: Firewall is not running. ) 

`netstat -anp | grep 9042 outputs

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2fI6Cgvn6eyWGl3WXdVdnhadUhwNlF4OVFBTVVNdXRxNF8w

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2fI6Cgvn6eyRWs0MXo4TW9DZTNReHdZbGZFUTJwUVI2Qk1F

And I can connect to 10.5.0.201 and 10.5.0.203 via cqlsh

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2fI6Cgvn6eyNE1zaE9pbEYwcUFHLTZWeEJwbS1OWlkxOHBn

Comment: @Abhinandan 10.5.0.203 => ( startup.log - http://pastebin.com/f0EC8ZA9 & agent.log - http://pastebin.com/Kw8EMYkG ) 

10.5.0.201 => ( startup.log -  http://pastebin.com/m8nmeYdD  & agent.log - http://pastebin.com/XEX3w5TR )